# How to echo a variable in Literals

Tags: php, wordpress, twig

is there a way in twig to echo a variable in literals, like this?

```
{{ mb.get_the_post_thumbnail( post.ID, 'full', {'class': 'sec-mitarbeiter-image {{objectPositionClass}} '} ) }}
```

Result:

class="sec-mitarbeiter-image {{objectPositionClass}}"

**Expected**:

class="sec-mitarbeiter-image object-position-top"

Comment: you miss to use $ with variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want simple string [concatenation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#other-operators):

```
{{ mb.get_the_post_thumbnail(post.ID, 'full', {
    'class': 'sec-mitarbeiter-image ' ~ objectPositionClass
}) }}
```

Or [interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#string-interpolation):

```
{{ mb.get_the_post_thumbnail(post.ID, 'full', {
    'class': "sec-mitarbeiter-image #{objectPositionClass}"
}) }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
{{ mb.get_the_post_thumbnail( post.ID, 'full', {'class': `sec-mitarbeiter-image $objectPositionClass `} ) }}
```

Comment: `{{ ` work similar like `<?php` so you can't  use it again for class name until  you close the first one

Comment: @Yogendra Yes, you're right. I have updated the code.

Comment: Twig does not use `$` to reference variables